# ¿Cómo devolver el resultado de otra función (callback)?

Tags: javascript, callback

Estoy ejecutando una función que debe llamar a otra. El resultado de la primera función depende de la segunda, pero la primera función no se espera al resultado de la primera para devolverlo.
Este código explica mejor:

```
function confirmar(mensaje){
    var r = false;
    bootbox.confirm(mensaje, function (res) {
        if(res) r = true;
    });
    return r;
}
```

El confirm muestra un modal. Sin que el usuario diga "Sí" o "No", ya la función `confirmar` ha devuelto false. Necesito que la función confirmar se espere a que se ejecute el confirm.

Comment: ¿Qué es bootbox?

Comment: Para qué necesitas una nueva función si `bootbox.confirm()` ya provee de un `callback` ?

Answer (score 2):

No puedes hacer lo que intentas de esa forma. `bootbox.confirm()` es un método que mostrará un mensaje de confirmación el cual, en este caso el usuario, sea el que con un click o presionando un botón, dispare la función de callback que toma como segundo argumento.
En tu función el valor de r siempre va a resultar false, ya que es devuelto antes de que haya cualquier respuesta.

Lo que puedes hacer:

```js
function confirmar(mensaje, callback){
    var r = false;
    bootbox.confirm(mensaje, function (res) {
      if(res) r = true;
      callback(r);
    });
}

confirmar('¿Te gusta programar?', function(res){
  // Aquí esta tu respuesta
  console.log(res);
  bootbox.alert(`Tu respuesta : ${res}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/releases/download/v4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
```

**Pero esto sería volver a rizar el rizo**, sería totalmente hacer lo mismo que ya hace `bootbox.confirm();`

Sería más fácil directamente :

```js
bootbox.confirm('¿Te gusta programar?', function (res) {
  bootbox.alert(`Tu respuesta : ${res}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/releases/download/v4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
```